# Exclude an .erb asset from cache in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have an assets, `projects.css.scss.erb`, like this :

```
<% Project.all.each do |project| %>
  $color: <%= project.color %>;
  #project-<%= project.id %> {
    .carousel {
      border-color: $color;
    }
  }
<% end %>
```

Its goal is to generate as many projects specific css directives as projects count. This assets is include in my `application.css.scss` with a `require` directive.

All works fine !

But problem comes when i add a new project or when i change a project's color... Rails doesn't compile the asset anymore because the source has no changes...

I'm looking for a solution to force rails to always recompile `projects.css.scss.erb` or to exclude it from the sprockets cache...

Someone knows a solution ??

**UPDATE**

Another way could be recompile `projects.css.scss.erb` only when a new project is created or a project is modify.

Comment: You might stumble with performance problems going like this, if you will have many accesses in your site. This seems a great place to use inline style, according to the project.

Comment: This is insane. Use JS.

Comment: Even in only one ??? Here i have only one simple css style but i have to add some shadow and others styles with project's specific color... And do this inline is hell on earth.

Comment: In fact, the `projects.css.scss.erb` does not need to recompile each requests. They are 2 cases it needs : when a new project is created and when a project is modify. Maybe can i force recompile this assest in the controller / model ??

Comment: Render the value as an inline style. If there is an ID-targeted style for each project, you aren't saving yourself any trouble by putting them into a CSS file.